# (Bootstrap 4) Scroll to top of tab-pane with a sticky Nav

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, scrollview, panel

I have a sticky navigation (sticks to top of the screen) that toggles between tabbed panels using Bootstrap 4. When I click on a particular tab, and scroll down, clicking on a different tab makes it so that the content of that panel is shown from the same vertical point where I was in the first panel.

How do I make it so that when I click on the new tab, the page scrolls to the top of the panel? I know that I can simply add IDs, but all the a tags and div tags already have their IDs - but it doesn't work.

```
<ul class="sticky-top nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Realized I can do it quite simply with JQuery.

```
 $(".nav-item a").click(function() {
        $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
            scrollTop: $("#nav-tabContent").offset().top-70
        }, 200);
    });
```